# Iterator removing object property

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java collection framework. But am stuck with iterators.

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Employee> list = new LinkedList <Employee>();

    list.add(new Employee("A", "A", "A",
            "A", "A", 1, "A", 1));
    list.add(new Employee("A", "A", "A",
            "A", "A", 1, "A", 2));
    list.add(new Employee("A", "A", "A",
            "A", "A", 1, "A", 3));
    list.add(new Employee("A", "A", "A",
            "A", "A", 1, "A", 4));
    list.add(new Employee("A", "A", "A",
            "A", "A", 1, "A", 5));
    list.add(new Employee("A", "A", "A",
            "A", "A", 1, "A", 6));

    for (Employee a : list) {
        System.out.println(a.getEmployeeID());
    }

    System.out.println("before\n");

    int selectedEmployeesID = 2;

    Iterator<Employee> empIt = list.listIterator();

    Employee current = empIt.next();

    while (empIt.hasNext()) {

        if (current.getEmployeeID() == selectedEmployeesID) {
            empIt.remove();
        }

    }
    for (Employee a : list) {
        System.out.println(a.getEmployeeID());
    }

}
```

Can anyone explain why the iterator does not remove from the LinkedList.

Comment: Are you sure `empIt.remove()` is ever called?  Have you tried stepping through the code in your debugger?

Comment: Where is _Employee_ defined? But Peter is right: debug your code and you should understand it a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never doing next inside loop. Try

```
Iterator<Employee> empIt = list.listIterator();    

    while (empIt.hasNext()) {
        Employee current = empIt.next();
        if (current.getEmployeeID() == selectedEmployeesID) {
            empIt.remove();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that `Employee current = empIt.next();` inside loop and
You have to remove it from list not from iterator

While removing values from iterator/list in a loop it will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. In order to handle that when list items are added or removed you have to reassign the iterator

```
Iterator<Employee> empIt = list.listIterator();    

while (empIt.hasNext()) {
    Employee current = empIt.next();
    if (current.getEmployeeID() == selectedEmployeesID) {
       // empIt.remove();
         list.remove(current);//to remove from list
        empIt = list.listIterator(); //For ConcurrentModificationExceptionHandling  
    }

}
```